# How to solve the error kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer Connection reset by ::1 port 2022

Tags: linux, ssh, kali-linux, openssh, remote

I use Kali linux and I would like to connect in localhost on my own system with ssh but when I do

> ssh root@localhost -p 2022

I get the error

> kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
> Connection reset by ::1 port 2022

I don't know what is misconfigured. I tried every method I could find on google that worked for others but it didn't work for me. I've been searching the web for two days without success. Need help please!

> ssh localhost
> Output

```
morel@localhost's password: 
Linux idris 5.18.0-kali7-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 5.18.16-1kali1   (2022-08-31) x86_64

The programs included with the Kali GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Kali GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Mon Sep 26 11:07:26 2022 from ::1
```

My sshd_config file

```
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
#   UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts.d/%k
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

Comment: My sshd_config file followed by "This is the ssh **client** system-wide configuration file". You should take more attention to important details like this when asking the question (you provided the wrong file). Also, running the client in debug mode and more importantly, checking the server's logs can help.

Comment: And as it's supposed to work out of the box on port 22 from the node to itself, you should explain why it went to port 2022 and what other changes were made. Is there any tunnel involved?

Comment: The fact is that my server and my client are on the same workstation. the objective is to connect to my own pc from my own pc so I do not know in this case if I am supposed to have 2 sshd_config files and for the port, I would like to access it from this port precisely or from another because when I try port 22 the system tells me that the port is already in use